# Does the headphones jack socket design affect performance?

Tags: connection, headphone-jack, 3.5mm

I recently bought a new smartphone - HTC One V. I noticed that its 3.5mm headphones jack socket design is a little bit different than what I'm used to - it's not completely flat:

[image]

Therefore, when I plug in my headphones, part of the plug is still outside:

[image]

I know that the important part of the plug is connected to the socket and that the part that is outside doesn't connect to anything, but I noticed that there are noises when I listen to music while walking or running, and I think that it has to do with the connectivity of the headphones jack.

Could it be related to the rounded headphones jack design? Could this design cause connectivity problems?
I see this jack design more and more today, yet it looks less safe and less stable than the regular flat jack design.

**Edit:**
I found two threads regarding the same issue on the HTC One X - [(1)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1720212), [(2)](http://www.htconeforum.com/forum/htc-one-x-help/300-htc-one-x-sound-issues-headphones.html). I know that it might be model-specific but I thought that it's related to the jack design as well.

Comment: Sorry, but questions about phones are off topic for Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.  I don't think there is that much interference outside just outside the device to noticeably affect quality.

To test this, move your device next to something that's using lots of power, such as your TV or computer.  If the quality decreases, you know that there might be a problem with insulation, and the short socket may play a role.

Comment: Just tested this, the quality didn't decrease at all.

Comment: So then the problem has nothing to do with interference.

Answer (score 0):

To give mechanically reliable contact, a plug should always seat fully into a socket.  If one could X-ray your phone, you'd probably see that the springy contact internally that should seat into the groove around the end of the plug hasn't seated because you couldn't get the plug in all the way.  That's why you're experiencing what sounds like noise when you walk or run:  The plug is making and breaking contact as you jossle it.

What's going on is that the manufacturer is forcing you (well, pushing you) to buy only their accessories, which have plugs that are thin enough that they will fit.

Comment: The thing is, even the HTC headphones that came with the device, don't go in all the way. And even with them I experience those noises!

Comment: I cannot agree with your saying that this is intended to encourage users to buy OEM accessories.  I'd say that this allows more space for electronics and for the casing just outside the jack by shrinking the jack inside the device, at the cost of a small amount of reliability and performance.